# ngx-translate: Event to detect changing language (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, ngx-translate, angular13

I want to detect the switch of the "current language" using **ngx-translate** library.

Which js event I can use to achieve that?

To better understand what I mean, please check this simple example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-yvbmgu

I want to detect the change of the currentLang from the "diff" component, on ngOnInit().

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can subscribe to TranslateService's `onLangChange` observable to listen to language change events.

```ts
    ngOnInit() {
      console.log(this.translate.currentLang);
      this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
        console.log(event.lang);
      });
    }
```

[TranslateService API](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#translateservice)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Angular's own BehaviorSubject to detect the language change.
In this way:

Write this Code in a General Service:

```
   public langObsevable: BehaviorSubject<string> = new 
       BehaviorSubject<string>(null);

   public onLanguageChanged(lang:string){
     this.langObsevable.next(lang);
   }
```

Now you can apply language changes in other components by subscribing, as below

```
  this.generalService.langObsevable.subscribe(res => {
     translate.use(res);
  });
```